# Setting UILabel text alignment to center not working in English locale switch from Arabic in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, arabic, arabic-support

I have a UILabel which I want to align center. When I choose align center in storyboard, it works fine when the language is Arabic, which is the default. If I switch to English, it aligns to left. I tried adding in code `bioLabel.textAlignment = .center`, but does not work properly. How to align UILabel to center in both English and Arabic?

[image]
[image]

Comment: can you add screen shot also.

Comment: Hi @jsloop add your label property screenshot here for more clarity.

Comment: Added screenshots.

Comment: after changing the language restart app and check once, is it working fine.

Comment: Restarting the app makes the label align center for the current language, but when I switch, it is not in center.

Comment: I am not sure why the question is downvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If after changing language shifts your label i think you did not give proper constraints. give constraints like, greater than or equal to left and right both and horizontal in container and top from above if you want. Then user UIView's appearance for rightToLeft and leftToRight.

Comment: I had given trailing space 16, leading space 16, bottom space 8, top space to view 60 as constraints.

Comment: make leading and trailing space greater than or equal to and made label text center from storyboard

Comment: Wow! Works great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please make yourself familiar with [Supporting Right-to-Left Languages](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages.html). While this reference is focussed on macOS, the concepts apply to both platforms. In addition, validate that you view can handle textual changes in general.

Comment: It works for natural alignment. I am having issues only when aligning center.